# DockerHub not updating repository timestamp when updated repo pushed with same tag

Tags: docker, dockerhub

When I push an updated Docker image to DockerHub using the same repository name and tag (version number), the new layers appear to be uploaded to DockerHub, and my DockerHub UI main page indicates the repository with that name was updated "nn minutes ago".

But when I select that repository and the UI transitions to the page for that repository, the UI indicates "Updated 1 week, 4 days ago" and under Properties, the original date still appears.

Shouldn't the timestamp information on this page reflect the latest update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted this same question to the Docker Forum just now and received the following reply:

We should definitely have better "updated" information. I'll check to see if I can find out why that elapsed time in the upper right corner is so off from the last push.